# Suming rows with a condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to read a file called 'data2' and compute the sum of '5s' for each row and write them to a file. My following code creates a column named 'total' and prints it. My issue is that my code just writes back my original data.

```
id     score1 score2 score3 score4
1425     5      3     5       5
6271     4      3     5       2
81729    2      3     3       3
515268   5      3     2       5
```

And the code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("data2",index_col=0)
df['total'] = df.iloc[:,1:-1].eq(5).sum(axis=1)

print(df['total'])
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `df.eq(5).sum(1)` instead?

Comment: I would write a lambda function that sums all 5's across the columns (def sum_5s_only():....) and then use it as such: df['total'] = df.apply(lamba row: sum_5s_only(row), axis=1) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html